# How to use sprintf/fprintf to print a string inside a cell array in matlab?

Tags: arrays, string, matlab, printf, cell-array

I was wondering if it was possible to use sprintf or fprintf to print something to a cell array.

In a structure `A` I have

```
A.labels = {'A' 'B' 'C' 'D'}
```

and I have a string/cell array

```
B = {'E' 'F' 'G' 'H'}
```

and I want to print into a new structure `C` such that I want

```
C.labels = {'A-E', 'B-F', 'C-G', 'E-H'}
```

In the code below I am just trying to check how to do the first entry and then once I figure that out I can do the rest myself.

```
C(1).labels = fprintf('%s -%s',B{1},A(1).labels);
```

But this does not do the job. How can I fix this?

Comment: @knedlsepp thanks for the edit.. sorry if it was annoying to read!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you type `help fprintf` it says:

> fprintf - Write data to text file

But you want `help sprintf`:

> sprintf - Format data into string

So you can fix your problem using:

```
C.labels = cellfun(@(x,y) sprintf('%s-%s',x,y), A.labels, B, 'uni',0)
```

This uses: `cellfun` to take corresponding pairs of `A.labels` and `B` and feeds it to the function `@(x,y) sprintf('%s-%s',x,y)`, which uses `sprintf`.

You could also use a regular `for` loop of course. I want to add also that what you currently have is a structure with a single `cell`-entry of length four instead of four structures each having a single entry.

Comment: Ah thanks.. I wasn't aware of this cellfun before.. thank you.

Comment: @MaheenSiddiqui: You could use a `for` loop instead of `cellfun`. The most important fix here is, that you need to use `sprintf` instead of `fprintf`.

Comment: @knedlsepp - Have you considered using `sprintfc`? It's an undocumented function: http://undocumentedmatlab.com/blog/sprintfc-undocumented-helper-function

Comment: @rayryeng: Never heard about it. I guess in this case `strcat` would suffice. So this is basically `cellfun`+`sprintf` for a single cell-array?

Comment: Pretty much! You haven't heard of it because it is undocumented after all :) lol.  `sprintfc` is a very powerful function.  It essentially takes data and converts it into a cell array of entries.  It has been shown that it is much faster than using `cellfun` with `uni=0.`

Comment: @rayryeng: Oh, interesting. I don't see how we can use it here though.

Answer (score 2):

This can be done very simply with [`strcat`](http://es.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/strcat.html):

```
C.labels = strcat(A.labels, '-', B);
```

Comment: Ha. Just when I write my comment about `strcat`, you turn up. :-D

Comment: Actually I turned up 13 seconds earlier :-P